# SQL : How to SELECT a record where certain attributes are null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014 database, and SQL Server Management Studio to create and run queries.

Tables are :

```
Persons

| ID | personName |
+----+------------+
| 1  |    Hamish  |
| 2  |    Morag   |
| 3  |    Ewan    |

Cars

| ID | CarName |
+----+---------+
| 1  |  Humber |
| 2  |  Austen |
| 3  |  Morris |

Gadgets

| ID | GadgetName |
+----+------------+
| 1  |  Cassette  |
| 2  |     CD     |
| 3  |   Radio    |

CarToPersonMap

| ID | CarID | PersonID |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1  |   1   |    1     |
| 2  |   2   |    1     |
| 3  |   3   |    2     |

CarToGadgetMap

| ID | CarID | GadgetID |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1  |   2   |    2     |
```

The map tables have the appropriate foreign keys.

I want to find people who have a Cars but none of the Cars have gadgets. So in the example above I want to find Morag who has a Car with no Gadgets. Hamish has 2 Cars but 1 one the Cars has a gadget so I do not want the ResultSet to include Hamish.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Seems like what you actually want is a `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2):

Left join the CarToGadgetMap to the CarToPersonMap.

Then group by the person.

Those persons will be having more than 0 cars but 0 gadgets.

> ```
> select PersonName
> from Persons as Person
> left join CarToPersonMap as CarPerson
>   on CarPerson.PersonId = Person.ID
> left join CarToGadgetMap as CarGadget
>   on CarGadget.carId = CarPerson.CarId
> group by Person.ID, PersonName
> having count(CarPerson.CarID) > 0    -- has car(s)
>    and count(CarGadget.GadgetID) = 0 -- no gadgets
> ```

| PersonName |
| --- |
| Morag |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=2e4a4be65d55d6aa89841d800fe0cd36)*

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a couple of CTEs:

```
With CarGadgetCount AS (
         SELECT c.ID as CarID, 
                SUM(CASE cg.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GadgetCount
         FROM Car c 
              LEFT JOIN CarToGadgetMap cg
                        ON cg.CarID = c.ID
         GROUP BY c.ID
    ),
    PersonCarCount AS (
         SELECT p.ID as PersonID, 
                SUM(CASE cp.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CarCount
         FROM Person p 
              LEFT JOIN CarToPersonMap cp
                        ON cp.PersonID = p.ID
    )
    PersonGadgetCount AS (
         SELECT p.ID AS PersonID,
                SUM(CASE WHEN cg.GadgetCount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE cg.GadgetCount END) as GadgetCount
         FROM Person p
              LEFT JOIN CarToPersonMap cp
                        ON cp.PersonID = p.ID
              LEFT JOIN CarGadgetCount cg 
                         ON cg.CarID = cp.CarID
         GROUP BY p.ID
    )
SELECT p.personName 
FROM Person p
     INNER JOIN PersonGadgetCount pg
                ON pg.PersonID = p.ID
     INNER JOIN PersonCarCount pc 
                ON pc.PersonID = p.ID
WHERE pc.CarCount > 0
      AND pg.GadgetCount = 0;
```

That way, if you want to actually see who has cars and who has gadgets, then you can switch the WHERE clause and specified columns in the select

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` also to get the expected output. The query will be something like,

```
SELECT DISTINCT personName
FROM Persons p 
WHERE 
    EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM CarToPersonMap WHERE  personId = p.ID )
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
            FROM CarToGadgetMap cgm 
            JOIN CarToPersonMap cpm ON cpm.personId = p.ID AND cpm.carId = cgm.carId)
```

[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=e8c7ba276616e52c0a3be4dac1a5f040) is the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation inside an `EXISTS`

```sql
SELECT personName
FROM Persons p 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM CarToPersonMap cpm
    LEFT JOIN CarToGadgetMap cgm ON cpm.carId = cgm.carID
    WHERE cpm.personId = p.ID
    HAVING COUNT(cgm.carID) = 0
);
```

What this says is:

- Get all `Persons` that have rows in the subquery.
- That subquery is all of their `CarToPersonMap`, left joined with relevant `CarToGadgetMap`.
- There must be no rows which have a matching `CarToGadgetMap` value (because `COUNT` only counts non-nulls).

**[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=e5a197b3b4b8925463880f518ba16fbb)**